# i got a error on php file for my school project

Tags: php

> Notice: Undefined variable: upid in C:\wamp\www\probeer\opvragen.php on line 112

```
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0007  264840  {main}( )   ..\opvragen.php:0
```

**line 112**

```
echo '<a href="opvragen.php?upid='.$upid.'\" class="btn-default">Update</a></td></tr>';
```

Comment: Can you post the code with line 112 ?

Comment: Error seems pretty straight forward. `$upid` is not defined.

Comment: Your variable `$upid` does not exist. Do something like `$upid = 'foo';` before line 112 and you'll at least get no error.

Comment: It means that $upid isn't defined. Can you show us where you'd define it?

Comment: why you guys make negative review on the question? As He is school guy and without helping him you are making down vote on question.

Comment: @HarshSanghani how have we not helped? We gave a link `719917` views, numerous answers, and is the exact issue to the question. A research effort is expected before posting. There is nothing to support that occurred here. I can't even begin to guess where the OP thinks `$upid` was defined.

Answer (score 1):

To simply answer your question the variable `$upid` is not defined, just like your error says.

Your are trying to echo out the content of the variable `$upid` right here:
`?upid='.$upid.'`

So somewhere above line 112 in your file, `$upid` should be assigned a value, but it isn't. 
If you on line 111 do this:

```
$upid = "Test";
```

Then your script wont throw the error, but you have to actually assign the value you want for it, so its time to look at your code where you are supposed to define it.

Comment: its like a school task i have to make it work but i cant find upid maby i can send you my code

Comment: @BramAnseeuw can you please show some code above that line, so we can find issue within your code.